# C++ - Friend function unable to be called in main?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Im having trouble with a multi-file setup. Im working in visual studio, and, for whatever reason, my friend function in my class is not being defined in main. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

BullCow.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

class BullCow {

    public:

        BullCow();

        friend int getWins();

        static int Wins;

    private:

        int Attempts;

};
```

BullCow.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BullCow.h"



int BullCow::Wins = 0;

int getWins() {

    return Wins;

}
```

BullCowMain.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BullCow.h"

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    std::cout << getWins();


    return 0;
}
```

Note: It's an incomplete program, so some code (srand) is not used yet. I just included everything to better help figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Why do you need this?  `BullCow::Wins` is `public`, so `main()` can just access it directly: `std::cout << BullCow::Wins;`.  `friend` is for granting access to `private`/`protected` members instead.

Comment: You're right - I just ran into this problem and wanted to sort it out first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getWins()` needs at least a declaration in the `.h` file.

Since it's a friend, `getWins()` is not a member of the class, so it must be declared either directly in `BullCowMain.cpp` or in some file `BullCowMain.cpp` includes.

Add this somewhere outside of the class in your header:

```
int getWins();
```

---

Also, inside `getwins`, the return should be:

```
return BullCow::Wins;
```

<sup>Thanks @user4581301!</sup>

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help -- this seemed to work. Just a question I had, if you'd be kind enough to answer...

When you're making friend overloaded operators, does this still apply? I had an assignment over the past semester that used friend overloaded operators in a class that was declared in a .h file, defined in a class implementation file, and used in a main file without the use of prototyping. Why did that work then but not in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @destin715 putting `friend void foo();` in the class means “there’s a function `foo` somewhere that’s not part of the me. Let that function access the private/protected members of any of my objects that it sees.” So it’s not declaring a function at all, but just marking a function as “friendly.” If I understand you correctly, the definition (do you mean declaration?) in the implementation file was simply ignored.

Comment: The code had a declaration of overloaded operators as friends (+, - >>, etc) in the class interface in the header file. In the file where the functions are defined, I defined the functions as normal and wrote their implementation. When I used it in my main file, I didn't need to prototype them again for them to work.